# How to enable CORS with a java restful web service on JBoss AS

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, jboss, cors

I have a very simple Java RESTful web service that includes two methods for GET and POST requests. I am using Jboss Application server 7 on OpenShift platform.

I need to enable JavaScript clients to consume the service using Ajax by sending or receiving JSON data.

The web service is running without problems. I can consume it using Ajax from a script in the same application, but I need to consume it from other applications on other domains.

How do I enable Cross-Origin-Request-Sharing (CORS) on my REST endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this header to your response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

For example, for servlets you would do this:

Alternatively, you can add the `jetty-servlets.jar` library as a dependency and add this filter to your web.xml. This will allow CORS for all of your web services.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you only need a specific service annotated, first we'll need more information about what library you're using to implement your RESTful service.

Comment: I know that I need to add that header to the response, I just don't know how. I tried adding jetty-servlets as a maven dependency to pom.xml, and adding the filter to web.xml but it didn't work. does it support JBoss AS ?

Comment: I just used Netbeans to create the web service inside a maven web application which by default didn't include a web.xml file. I'm using annotations from javax.ws.rs package.

Comment: I changed the server to wildfly 8 and it worked, thank you very much for your help